# Asus X501A - Screen is black, lights come on when booted

Tags: hardware-failure

I have an [Asus X501A](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X501A/) laptop. The hard drive came loose so I removed the keyboard top to access the hard drive, plugged it back in and reassembled my laptop.

The laptop worked fine for three days until my laptop failed to turn on. Specifically, the screen remains black while the charger light, etc turn on as normal. Nothing displays on the laptop screen. The laptop screen did come back for half an hour at one point, but I have not been able to repeat this.

I tried the turn off trick with the power button/battery and it did not help. The fan has stopped spinning when I turn it on (it doesn't spin any more when i boot it). Not had a problem until now.

Any advice on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: your hard drive came loose? how is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

By chance did you drop your laptop? I've never heard of a hard drive coming loose without some sort of impact being involved. The symptoms you're mentioning are leading me to thinking you've got a major hardware failure (motherboard). One thing worth trying is to pull it back apart and ensure you have good connections made in case anything else came loose - specifically the cable running from your monitor to your motherboard. The next thing I'd do is plug in an external monitor to it if you're still having issues. If that works then you may have an issue with your display/video card. If not and the fans still aren't spinning up then you have a motherboard/power issue.